# Using SSH key for install npm module from private repository inside docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, ssh, private-key

I make container for nodejs project. Inside the project I am using private repository. I need an access to it. For that I am using next Dockerfile

```
FROM node:15

RUN echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
COPY keys/ssh_config /root/.ssh/config
COPY keys/bitbucket /root/.ssh/bitbucket
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/bitbucket

RUN npm install -g typescript ts-node
WORKDIR /var/www
EXPOSE 3000
```

ssh_config file is

```
Host bitbucket.org
     IdentityFile /root/.ssh/bitbucket
     StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

in my package.json I added next line

```
"my-interfaces": "git+ssh://bitbucket.org:MY_USER_NAME/my-interfaces.git#master",
```

After building container using docker-compose, I login inside container and run
`npm i`
but in the end I see next error

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command git ls-remote ssh://git@bitbucket.org/MY_USER_NAME/my-interfaces.git
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-30T08_19_38_999Z-debug.log
```

I tried another way, I generate SSH key inside container and added public key to bitbucket, but I see the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the host system’s ssh access.

```
FROM node:15

RUN apt install openssh-client git

RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN --mount=type=ssh npm install -g typescript ts-node
WORKDIR /var/www
EXPOSE 3000
```

The image must be built as follows:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default .
```

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#to-enable-buildkit-builds